# Very slow many to many eager loading in sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Recently one of my colleague pointed out that many-to-many association in sequelize query has O(n²) of time complexity, about which I didn't find anywhere online. Since this association is frequently observed in b/w real-world data and I have aready used it at many places in my projects it is very alarming for the developers that this downside isn't mentioned anywhere on the internet.
Consider one case where I have defined following query between two tables A & B.

```js
db.A.findAll({
   include: [
     { modal: db.B }, 
     { modal: db.C }
   ]
})
```

Here A & B have many to many association b/w them.
If B and C has large no of associated content(let's say around 100) the query becomes very slow. It takes about 40-50 second to execute this query.
This slow execution time can only be explained if sequelize is checking each entries in both the table sequentially by permutating through them.
I also tried researching about how mysql queries with eager loading are internally implemented in sequelize but got nothing on it.
Can someone explain the more concrete reason behind this? I used eager loading this way assuming that Sequelize internally go through Join table before fetching the content from B & C table.

**EDIT:**

The relationship between them is defined as follows:

```js
db.A.belongsToMany(models.B, { through: AB, foreignKey: 'aId' });
db.B.belongsToMany(models.A, { through: AB, foreignKey: 'bId' });
```

Comment: Can you provide EXPLAIN text results when this is processed by MySQL/MariaDB?  We should be able to find missing indexes.  Also please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table(s) for consideration.

Comment: How A and B are associated?

Comment: They are associated using many-to-many relationship.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Currently I'm busy with work but I will try to add these details by the end of this week.